# I have problem with resizing web screen and div elements on it

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

This is on a normal window size:

[image: normal screen size]

And this is how it looks like when I resize window

[image: resized version]

I want to move these 2 elements from bottom to up smoothly when someone resizes the web screen. I even tried to add here an extra element between up elements and down elements, but it still doesn't work.

I know that I can use `@medi`" elements, but it doesn't make it move smoothly. Is there any other way to do this?

```css
.nav-bar {
  background-color: #e4e8ea;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 840px;
  z-index: 101;
}

.nav-bar-top {
  height: 380px;
}

.nav-bar-top-button {
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar-top-button div {
  font-family: Multiround Pro;
}

.pop {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.fav {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.recently {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.home-button {
  background: url('/Images/home-page.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 35px 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 27px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
}

.pop-button {
  background: url('/Images/popular-button.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 27px 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
}

.fav-button {
  background: url('/Images/favourite-1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 24px 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
}

.recently-viewed-button {
  background: url('/Images/recently-viewed-1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 24px 13px;
  padding-top: 51px;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-bar-middle {
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-bar-bottom {
  height: 200px;
  width: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-bar-bottom-button {
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-bar-bottom div {
  font-family: Multiround Pro;
}

.support-button {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.support-button,
.setting-button {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.support-button {
  background: url('/Images/support-1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 24px 20px;
  padding: 60px 0px 0px 4px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
}

.setting-button {
  background: url('/Images/settings.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px;
  background-position: 24px 20px;
  padding: 60px 0px 0px 4px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  height: 90px;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-bar-top">
    <div class="nav-bar-top-button">
      <div class="home-button" title="Home">
        <div>Home</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-top-button">
      <div class="pop-button">
        <div class="pop">Popular</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-top-button">
      <div class="fav-button">
        <div class="fav">Favourites</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-top-button">
      <div class="recently-viewed-button">
        <div class="recently">Recently viewed</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar-middle">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-bar-bottom">
    <div class="nav-bar-bottom-button">
      <div class="support-button">Support</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-bottom-button">
      <div class="setting-button">Setting</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: perhaps what you're looking for is the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

Comment: but how can i do this in css or html without js?

Comment: I think the problem should be your `.nav-bar` is having a fix height.